# Android uses Google's admob advertising SDK for ANR and memory overflow

Tags: sdk, admob

The logs I collected on firebase are as follows:

1. Log of ANR
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb7ge.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Epu0.png)
2. Memory overflow logs
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1DQn.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGunh.png)

I want to know the cause of these problems and how to solve them. I am just a simple display advertisement. These are problems that I didn't encounter during testing and can't reproduce

Comment: These ANRs are pretty common coming from the Ads library. One way is to add optimisation flags, see here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/optimize-initialization. This doesn't completely solve the issue, but might lower the occurrence of this issue.